# Folder not created with $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop fs -mkdir /user/hive/warehouse

Tags: hadoop, configuration, installation, hive

Hey I am installing HIVE in a Hadoop 2.7.3 Single Node cluster ,and I am not able to Create folder using

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop fs -mkdir /user/hive/warehouse
16/11/11 14:43:25 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
mkdir: `/user/hive/warehouse': No such file or directory
```

JPS for Hadoop is working fine:

```
jps
15411 NodeManager
15285 ResourceManager
15718 Jps
14904 DataNode
14793 NameNode
15116 SecondaryNameNode
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can give with -p, which will create parent path

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/hive/warehouse
```

Answer (score 1):

you should create one b one, which means for creating `/user/hive/warehouse` folder first you should have `/user` folder and inside it you should have `/user/hive` folder, then only you can create `/user/hive/warehouse` folder. You cannot directly create with it.